# git clone to AWS Codecommit repo returns 403

Tags: git, git-remote, aws-codecommit

I am trying to clone source code hosted in an AWS Codecommit Repo using HTTP-GRC method.

I have followed this setup guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/temporary-access.html?icmpid=docs_acc_console_connect#tc-role

```
git clone codecommit::us-west-2://my-code-repo 
returns:
Cloning into 'common-ops-cdk'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-code-repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Here's some info that might come handy understanding what's wrong:

```
$ git config --list
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager-core
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=master
credential.helper=!aws codecommit credential-helper $@
credentials.helper=UseHttpPath=true
```

Any insights will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an IAM user with access to CodeCommit, then go to **Security Credentials** for that user and under the **HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit** section select the **Generate Credentials** button.

Use these to authenticate against the AWS git repo